# DropDownList SelectedindexChanged inside repeater does not fire

Tags: vb.net, repeater

I am using User Control Pages (.ascx). I have a repeater and inside it I have n DropDownList and some textboxes. I need to trigger SelectedIndexChanged event to get values from textbox.

This is the error that I get:
'ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.controls_claims_laborder_ascx'.

**HTML:**

```
<asp:Repeater ID="rptProducts" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <tr class="Header">
            <td>Eye</td>
            <td>Tarrif</td>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>Lab Price</td>
        </tr>
    </HeaderTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>
                <td> 
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlEye" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged" AutoPostBack="true">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="N/A" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Left" />
                        <asp:ListItem Text="Right" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTariff" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Code") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtDescription" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Description") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLabPrice" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Invoice") %>' />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
Private Sub ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlEye.SelectedIndexChanged
        Dim dEye As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)

        If ddlEye.SelectedItem.Value = "Right" Then
            lblLeftLensDesc.Text = "Description of the left lens"
            lblRightLensDesc.Text = dEye.SelectedItem.Text
        ElseIf ddlEye.SelectedItem.Value = "Left" Then
            lblLeftLensDesc.Text = dEye.SelectedItem.Text
            lblRightLensDesc.Text = "Description of the right lens"
        Else
            lblLeftLensDesc.Text = "Description of the left lens"
            lblRightLensDesc.Text = "Description of the right lens"
        End If
End Sub
```

I have also tried to dynamically create event for DropDownList but that still does not work.

```
Private Sub rptProducts_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles rptProducts.ItemDataBound
        Dim dlEye As DropDownList = e.Item.FindControl("ddlEye")
        Dim txtDesc As TextBox = e.Item.FindControl("txtDescription")

        If Not dlEye Is Nothing AndAlso Not txtDesc Is Nothing Then
            dlEye.SelectedIndexChanged += New EventHandler(ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged)
            dlEye.SelectedValue = txtDesc.Text
        End If

End Sub
```

**Repeater Binding Code:**

```
 Private Sub loadLineItems(ByVal strTransactionID As String)
     Dim objLineItems As ArrayList = Managers.LineItem.GetLineItems(CInt(strTransactionID))

     If objLineItems.Count > 0 Then
         rptProducts.DataSource = objLineItems
         rptProducts.DataBind()
     Else
         rptProducts.DataSource = Nothing
         rptProducts.DataBind()
     End If
End Sub

If Not IsPostBack Then
    loadLineItems(Session("pstrTransactionID").ToString())
End If
```

Comment: I assume that you are databinding the `Repeater`(or your `UserControl`) on every postback instead of only `If Not Page.IsPostaBack`.

Comment: No I do not bind on every postback

Comment: I believe you. But it would still be better to show the code where you databind it, not all the databinding stuff but the part where you call `rptProducts.DataBind()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is the error that I get: 'ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged' is not a
>   member of 'ASP.controls_claims_laborder_ascx'.

The reason is that your event handler is `Private`. You either need to make it `Protected` or `Public` or you can't add the event-handler declaratively on the ascx but you need to add it programmatically in codebehind (by using `Handles` or `AddHandler`).

So for example:

```
Protected Sub ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
    ' ...
End Sub
```

or (note the `Handles`)

```
Private Sub ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlEye.SelectedIndexChanged
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Here you need to remove following from ascx

```
OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged"
```

Side-note:  you use

```
AddHandler dlEye.SelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged
```

in VB.NET.

**Update**

> Thank you so much it worked. Perhaps you can help me with another
>   issue, I want to get the textbox value in the same row as the
>   DropDownList when setectedIndex changes?

You can get the `RepeaterItem` via `NamingContainer`, you just need to cast it accordingly. Then you can use `FindControl("ID")` to get the `TextBox`:

```
Protected Sub ddlEye_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) 
        Dim dEye As DropDownList = DirectCast(sender, DropDownList)
        Dim item = DirectCast(dEye.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)
        Dim txtTariff = DirectCast(item.FindControl("txtTariff"), TextBox)
        ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't get any errors now but the event still not firing

Comment: @G-Man: (note that I've edited my answer to provide the correct way in VB.NET to add the event handler). The problem seems not to be   in this UserControl anymore but where you DataBind the UserControl itself. What are you doing with it from the page? Have you checked if `Page_Load` get triggered if you select a different item in the `DropDownList` or if the postbacl doesn't happen at all?

Comment: The postback do happen when I select different value. Where should I add the event handler code you provided?

Comment: It should be redundant to add the event handler programmatcially. That is requiored only if you have to add controls dynamically. Howerver, the best place to do this is the repeaters `ItemCreated` event since that is triggered on every postback instead of only on databinding.

Comment: I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object when I add that code in ItemCreated event

Comment: @G-Man: have you checked the [type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeateritem.itemtype(v=vs.110).aspx) of the item? Since it's in the `ItemTemplate` you need to use `If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item OrElse e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem`. The first item is the header but there is no `DropDown` with this ID in  the header.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. Perhaps you can help me with another issue, I want to get the textbox value in the same row as the DropDownList when setectedIndex changes?

Comment: @G-Man: you can get the `RepeaterItem` via `dEye.NamingContainer`, you just need to cast it accoordingly. Then you can use `FindControl("ID")` to get them.

Comment: Can you give me example please?

Comment: @G-Man: i have added a sample. Btw, your original problem seems to be related to your instance variable `ddlEye`. Don't declare it since a repeater contsains multiple. Your `Handles ddlEye.SelectedIndexChanged` would normally not compile. Because it compiles it means that you have declared a variable `ddlEye` somewhere which caused the issue.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what went wrong but DropDownListSelectedIndexChanged event fires up even though
ddlGarmentList control was fired up :

CODE BEHIND:

```
public partial class NewStyleItem : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected StyleTemplateManager styleTempMngr = new StyleTemplateManager();

    protected StyleFabricationManager styleFabMngr = new StyleFabricationManager();

    protected List<ComponentReferenceView> ReferenceLookUpList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<ComponentReferenceView>)ViewState["ReferenceLookUpView"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["ReferenceLookUpView"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected List<ComponentReferenceView> ReferenceViewList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<ComponentReferenceView>)ViewState["CompReferenceView"];
        }
        set
        {
            ViewState["CompReferenceView"] = value;
        }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.IsPostBack == false)
        {
            LoadBrandList();
            ddlGarmentList.Enabled = false;

            //ReferenceLookUpList = new List<ComponentReferenceView>();
        }
        else
        {
        }

        //rptStyleComponents.DataSource = ReferenceLookUpList;
        //rptStyleComponents.DataBind();
    }

    protected void LoadBrandList()
    {
        BrandManager brandMngr = new BrandManager();
        ddlBrandList.Items.Clear();

        ddlBrandList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Select brand", Value = "" });
        foreach (Brand item in brandMngr.Brands())
        {
            ddlBrandList.Items.Add(new ListItem
            {
                Text = item.BrandDescription,
                Value = item.BrandCode
            });
        }
    }

    protected void LoadComponentInfo(string BrandCode)
    {
        if (styleTempMngr.FindTemplateByBrandCode(BrandCode) == true)
        {
            ReferenceLookUpList = (from StyleComponent i in styleFabMngr.ComponentList
                                   join StyleFabReference x in styleTempMngr.ReferenceList on
                                   i.SectionCode equals x.SectionCode
                                   select new ComponentReferenceView
                                   {
                                       InOrder = x.SortOrder,
                                       IsNeeded = x.IsRequired,
                                       SCode = x.SeriesCode,
                                       SecCode = x.SectionCode,
                                       SecName = i.SectionName,
                                       EntryValue = x.DataCharacter
                                   }).OrderBy(p => p.InOrder).ToList();

            ReferenceLookUpList.Where(row => row.SecCode == "BCODE").ToList()
                .ForEach(refItem => refItem.EntryValue = ddlBrandList.SelectedValue);

            var DistinctList = (from StyleFabReference x in styleTempMngr.ReferenceList.OrderBy(p => p.SortOrder).ToList()
                                where x.SectionCode != "SPCHAR" && x.SectionCode != "BCODE"
                                select x.SectionCode).Distinct().ToList();

            ReferenceViewList = (from StyleComponent i in styleFabMngr.ComponentList
                                 join x in DistinctList on
                                 i.SectionCode equals x
                                 select new ComponentReferenceView
                                 {
                                     SecCode = x,
                                     SecName = i.SectionName
                                 }).OrderBy(p => p.InOrder).ToList();
        }
        else
            ReferenceViewList = new List<ComponentReferenceView>();

        rptStyleComponents.DataSource = ReferenceViewList;
        rptStyleComponents.DataBind();

    }

    protected void LoadGarments(string ApparelCode)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlBrandList.SelectedValue) == true)
        {
            ddlGarmentList.SelectedIndex = 0;
            ddlGarmentList.Enabled = false;
        }
        else
        {
            ddlGarmentList.Enabled = true;
            GarmentManager gmMngr = new GarmentManager();
            List<Garment> garmentList = new List<Garment>();
            garmentList = gmMngr.GetGarmentsByBrand(ddlBrandList.SelectedValue, ApparelCode);
            ddlGarmentList.Items.Clear();
            ddlGarmentList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Select garment", Value = "" });

            foreach (Garment item in garmentList)
            {
                ddlGarmentList.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = item.GarmentDescription, Value = item.GarmentCode });
            }
        }
    }

    protected void ddlBrandList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtNewStyleNo.Text = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlBrandList.SelectedValue) == false)
            LoadComponentInfo(ddlBrandList.SelectedValue);
    }

    [Serializable]
    public class ComponentReferenceView
    {
        public string SCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string SecCode
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string SecName
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public int InOrder
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public bool IsNeeded
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
        public string EntryValue
        {
            get;
            set;
        }
    }

    protected void rptStyleComponents_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void rptStyleComponents_ItemCreated(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
        {
            DropDownList ddlControl = (DropDownList)e.Item.FindControl("ddlDataSelection");

            if (ddlControl != null)
            {
                ddlControl.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
                ddlControl.Items.Add(new ListItem { Text = "Select " + ReferenceViewList[e.Item.ItemIndex].SecName.ToLowerInvariant(), Value = "" });
                var itemlist = (from x in styleFabMngr.ComponentRowItems(ReferenceViewList[e.Item.ItemIndex].SecCode).AsEnumerable()
                                select new ListItem
                                {
                                    Text = x.Field<string>("col_name"),
                                    Value = x.Field<string>("col_value")
                                });
                ddlControl.Items.AddRange(itemlist.ToArray<ListItem>());

                ddlControl.EnableViewState = false;
                ddlControl.AutoPostBack = true;
                ddlControl.SelectedIndexChanged += new EventHandler(DropDownListSelectedIndexChanged);
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void DropDownListSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)sender;
        RepeaterItem item = (RepeaterItem)ddl.NamingContainer;

        ReferenceViewList[item.ItemIndex].EntryValue = ddl.SelectedValue;
        ConstructStyleNo();

        var Apparelfound = ReferenceViewList.Where(x => x.SecCode == "APCODE" &&
           string.IsNullOrEmpty(x.EntryValue) == false).FirstOrDefault();

        if (Apparelfound != null)
        {
            ddlGarmentList.Enabled = true;
            LoadGarments(Apparelfound.EntryValue);
        }
        else
        {
            ddlGarmentList.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void ConstructStyleNo()
    {
        foreach (ComponentReferenceView item in ReferenceViewList)
        {
            ReferenceLookUpList.Where(row => row.SecCode == item.SecCode).ToList()
                .ForEach(refItem => refItem.EntryValue = item.EntryValue);
        }

        string sResult = string.Empty;
        var result = (from x in ReferenceLookUpList.OrderBy(y => y.InOrder)
                      select x.EntryValue);

        txtNewStyleNo.Text = string.Empty;
        if (result != null)
            txtNewStyleNo.Text = String.Join("", result) + "0001";

    }

    private void ConstructStyleDescription()
    {
        txtStyleDescription.Text = ddlBrandList.SelectedItem.Text + "-" + ddlGarmentList.SelectedItem.Text;
    }

    protected void ddlGarmentList_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        txtStyleDescription.Text = string.Empty;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlGarmentList.SelectedValue) == false)
            ConstructStyleDescription();
    }
}
```

ASPX:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlNewFabrication" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <h1>
            New Style Item
            </h1>
            <br />
            <%--<usrCtrl:style_generation ID="stylegen_frm" runat="server">
            </usrCtrl:style_generation>--%>

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                  Brand :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlBrandList" runat="server" 
                        onselectedindexchanged="ddlBrandList_SelectedIndexChanged" 
                        AutoPostBack="True">
                    </asp:DropDownList> 
                </td>
            </tr>           
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2">
                &nbsp;
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Generated Style# :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewStyleNo" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    Style Description :
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtStyleDescription" runat="server" ReadOnly="true"></asp:TextBox>                   
                </td>
            </tr>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="rptStyleComponents" runat="server" 
                        onitemdatabound="rptStyleComponents_ItemDataBound" 
                        onitemcreated="rptStyleComponents_ItemCreated" 
                EnableViewState="True">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upnlComponent" runat="server">
                                <ContentTemplate>
                                     <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:Label ID="lblSectionName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("SecName")%>' ></asp:Label>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDataSelection" runat="server">
                                            </asp:DropDownList>                    
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>                               
                                </ContentTemplate>
                                <Triggers>
                                    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlDataSelection" />
                                </Triggers>
                            </asp:UpdatePanel>                           
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>   
        </table>
        <br />
        <table>
            <tr>
            <td colspan="2">Description Items</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Garment Type:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upGarment" runat="server" >
                    <ContentTemplate>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlGarmentList" runat="server" 
                            AppendDataBoundItems="True" AutoPostBack="True" 
                            onselectedindexchanged="ddlGarmentList_SelectedIndexChanged">
                            <asp:ListItem Text = "Select garment" Value = ""></asp:ListItem>    
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsGarment" runat="server" 
                            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:IRMSConnectionString %>" 
                            SelectCommand="Select * from Garments"></asp:SqlDataSource>
                    </ContentTemplate>
                    <Triggers>
                        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="ddlGarmentList"  />
                    </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>

                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cost Price:</td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCostPrice" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>SRP :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtSRP" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Quantity :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
                <td>Week :</td>
                <td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer to the question?